# jQuery - Append list with as many options as there are in PHP value

Tags: jquery, list, append

If I have a list such as:

```
<ol>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```

And I want to append with a li containing a number for the range of a number value so the output is:

```
<? $number = "5"; ?>
<ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ol>
```

How can I do this in jQuery?

For those who want to know what I am doing with this code then look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dnLbV/19/. I am applying the Fiddle to a lowest-unique penny auction wherein there are a limited number of bids.

Comment: I have posted an answer below but is there any particular reason you want to use a php variable to use as a variable in a javascript statement?  It seems like a waste of client side processing really when you could just render the page using that php variable purely server side and not have to worry about any javascript at all.

Comment: Yeah just follow my answer, its done purely server side rather than getting the client to process it.

Comment: For reference, the only time youd really need javascript to build the list for you is if you didn't know before the page loads how many options you were going to need, then you would perform an ajax query requestiong the number of items needed, then use javascript to populate the list.  But in your case this is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldnt be doing this in jQuery you would be doing it in php.  Unless you are doing an ajax call for example then you would be appending after the page has loaded using jQuery.  In PHP you would do it like this though.

```
<?php $number = "5"; ?>
<ol>
<?php 
    for($index = 1; $index <= $number; $index++)
       echo "<li>$index</li>";
?>
</ol>
```

Dont really see the point in doing it in jQuery unless its in response to some sort of ajax request.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13890/php-for-loops go here and we can talk about it more.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
var li = "";
for(var i=0;i<<?php echo $number;?>;i++){
    li += "<li>" + (i+1) + "</li>";
}
$("#listID").append(li);
```

HTML:

```
<ol id="listID">
</ol>
```

Just a note, it's entirely possible to do this in plain JavaScript by replacing `$("#listID").append(li);` with `document.getElementById("listID").innerHTML = li;`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
  $('ol').append('<li>'+ i +'</li>')
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4PSe/

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i =1; i <= <?php echo $number ?>; i++){
    $('<li />').html(i).appendTo('ol');
}
```